# Set local variable without deleting it when computer goes off-line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to set a local variable. 
I know I can use: 
set dummyX=C:\Program Files (x86)

But how do I make it this way that when a computer goes offline, the variable is remembered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

```
if not defined dummyX (
    setx dummyX "C:\Program Files (x86)"
    set " dummyX=C:\Program Files (x86)"
)
```

you need both setx and set because setx takes effect after the cmd.exe is started again.

Comment: That seems to be the thing that I was looking for. 
Thank you. :-)